# query with mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, express

this is my structure folder

-- express_example 

|---- app.js 

|---- models 

|-------- songs.js 

|-------- albums.js 

|---- and another files of expressjs

`song.js`

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
, Schema = mongoose.Schema
, ObjectId = Schema.ObjectId;

var SongSchema = new Schema({
name: {type: String, default: 'songname'}
, link: {type: String, default: './data/train.mp3'}
, date: {type: Date, default: Date.now()}
, position: {type: Number, default: 0}
, weekOnChart: {type: Number, default: 0}
, listend: {type: Number, default: 0}
});

mongoose.model('Song', SongSchema);
module.exports = SongSchema;
```

`album.js`

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
, Schema = mongoose.Schema
, SongSchema = require('./songs')
, ObjectId = Schema.ObjectId;

var AlbumSchema = new Schema({
name: {type: String, default: 'songname'}
, thumbnail: {type:String, default: './public/images/album/unghoangphuc/U1.jpg'}
, date: {type: Date, default: Date.now()}
, songs: [SongSchema]
});

mongoose.model('Album', AlbumSchema);
```

How could i put code query album by album id in file `album.js`

Answer (score 2):

example:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
  , Album = mongoose.model('Album'); 

app.get('/posts/:id', function(req, res, next) {
  Album.findById(req.params.id, function(err, album) {
    // album is available here
  });      
});
```

see http://mongoosejs.com/docs/finding-documents.html to learn more about finding docs.

PS: this is the third time that I answered your question :)

Comment: :) 3 times i got your answered, It's very useful for me.
Could I put query script in file `album.js` like a function, that function is  used when i need to call it in some seperate places

Comment: For simple and builtin queries, it's not neccessary to do so, and it's often handled by controllers instead of models. As for complex queries, you may add new methods to the model, see http://mongoosejs.com/docs/methods-statics.html

Comment: OK.. Thank you so much :D...I'm very glad about your help to me. I will try to help anothers like you help me.